# cluster of milk

Tags: food-chemistry, proteins

[image]I have a problem with milk when we are making yogurt in factory. When the milk pass through the machine it clogs the filter of the machine because the cluster that formed on the filter. My question is why that formed and what is a solution to the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does milk flake?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/why-does-milk-flake)

Comment: I don't think you will find many food engineering specialists here.